# Delete rows on a table with cascading foreign keys

Tags: postgresql, foreign-key, delete

I want to delete rows on Table A but it has foreign keys on Table B and Table D. And Table B has foreign keys in Table E and Table D has foreign key in table F. Can I delete all the cascading records from Table A to F in a simple script without making multiple delete scripts per table? In reality, Table A has around 20 table referencing to it.

Table A

- Table B

  - Table E
- Table C
- Table D

  - Table F

PostgreSQL version: 9.2.24

Comment: You can declare the foreign keys as `on delete cascade` then you only need to delete from table `A`

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but: Postgres 9.2 is [no longer supported](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/)  you should plan an upgrade as soon as possible.

Answer (score 1):

First, it depends on how your foreign keys are declared. Assuming tables like:

```
CREATE TABLE parent
( pid ... not null primary key
, ...
);

CREATE TABLE child
( ...
, pid ... not null
    references parent (pid)
        on delete <action>
        on update ...
...
);
```

action can be any of:

- NO ACTION
  Produce an error indicating that the deletion or update would create a foreign
  key constraint violation. If the constraint is deferred, this error will be
  produced at constraint check time if there still exist any referencing rows.
  This is the default action.
- RESTRICT
  Produce an error indicating that the deletion or update would create a foreign key constraint violation. This is the same as NO ACTION except that the check is not deferrable.
- CASCADE
  Delete any rows referencing the deleted row, or update the value of the referencing column to the new value of the referenced column, respectively.
- SET NULL
  Set the referencing column(s) to null.
- SET DEFAULT
  Set the referencing column(s) to their default values.

See https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/sql-createtable.html

If your foreign keys are declared as "on delete cascade" it is - in theory - sufficient to delete the root node. In practice, there may be physical limitations that restrict the total number of rows that can be deleted in one transaction.

If you want to experiment with the different actions you can use [Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.5). 9.5 is the oldest one available. If you are still on 9.2, consider upgrading to something more modern.